# Simple UIImageView Slideshow IOS timer issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im attempting to create a simple slideshow where the image of a UIImageView changes every three seconds. First I call `[self slideShow]` in my `viewDidLoad`. The Timer I have only runs once for some reason and I can't figure it out. Here are my other methods:

```
- (void)slideShow
{
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(imChange)
                                      userInfo:nil
                                       repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)imChange
{
    NSLog(@"%d",slideNum);
    switch (slideNum) {
        case 0:
            imView.image = img1;
        break;

        case 1:
             imView.image = img2;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

    slideNum++;

    if (slideNum > 1) {
        slideNum = 0;
    }
}
```

Edit: Timer is an instance variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this implementation -

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@selector(imChange)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];
```

because with timerWithTimeInterval parameter you should add your timer in **NSRunLoop** manually, like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```